# XML, XSL namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I'm new to XML especially namespaces. I made all the documents and everything seems to work fine, but I don't know whether I'm really using namespaces (which is requirement). Except that my html file are not valid because off this:
"Attribute xmlns:xsi not allowed here." and "Attribute xmlns:xslformatting not allowed here."

**QUESTIONS:**
1. Am I really using namespaces? (if not how should I reach this goal?)
2. How can I make XSL producing valid HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xslFormatting="urn:xslFormatting">
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="invoice.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://josefdraslar.cz/ schema.xsd" xmlns="http://josefdraslar.cz/">
    <buyerParty>
        <name>Martin</name>
        <surname>Vomáčka</surname>
        <address1>
                <street>Melantrichova</street>
                <number>470/8</number>
                <city>Praha</city>
                <postalZone>11000</postalZone>         
        </address1>
        <contact>
            <fastContact>
                <telephone>327345678</telephone>
                <mobile>608473748</mobile>
                <email>vomacka@gmail.com</email>
                <fax/>
            </fastContact>
            <address>
                <street>Melantrichova</street>
                <number>470/8</number>
                <city>Praha</city>
                <postalZone>11000</postalZone> 
                <notes>čtvrté dveře vlevo</notes>
            </address>
        </contact>
        <ico/>
    </buyerParty>
    <sellerParty>
        <name>Alza.cz a.s.</name>
        <address>
            <street>Jateční</street>
            <number>33a</number>
            <city>Praha</city>
            <postalZone>17000</postalZone>
            <notes/>
        </address>
        <contact>
            <telephone>327456709</telephone>
            <mobile>607359724</mobile>
            <email>info@alza.cz</email>
            <fax>225340190</fax>
        </contact>
        <ico>27082440</ico>
        <bankAccount>
            <number>2171532</number>
            <bank>
                <kode>0800</kode>
                <name>Česká spořitelna</name>
            </bank>
            <specificSymbol>345723</specificSymbol>
        </bankAccount>
    </sellerParty>
    <invoiceInfo>
        <issueDate>01.03.2015</issueDate>
        <maturity>30.03.2015</maturity>
        <invoiceNumber>345723</invoiceNumber>
        <note/>
        <numberOfItems>9</numberOfItems>
    </invoiceInfo>
    <sum>
        <withoutTax>90000</withoutTax>
        <tax>18900</tax>
        <containingTaxTotal>108900</containingTaxTotal>
    </sum>
    <invoiceLineItems>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1234</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SA</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1234</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia S</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1235</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SB</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1236</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SC</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1231</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SR</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1239</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SP</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1277</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SX</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1222</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SZ</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
        <invoiceItem>
            <itemNumber>1111</itemNumber>
            <itemName>Nokia SI</itemName>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <price>
                <perUnit>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </perUnit>
                <sum>
                    <withoutTax>10000</withoutTax>
                    <containingTax>12100</containingTax>
                </sum>
            </price>
        </invoiceItem>
    </invoiceLineItems>
</invoice>
```

XSL (to HTML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ins:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:ins="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://josefdraslar.cz/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xslFormatting="urn:xslFormatting">

    <ins:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />   
    <ins:template match="invoice">
        <ins:result-document href="invoice.html">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title> <ins:value-of select="sellerParty/name/text()"/></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="invoice.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="hlavni">
                    <h1>Faktura</h1>

                    <ins:apply-templates/>


                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        </ins:result-document>
    </ins:template>


    <ins:template match="buyerParty">
        <h2>Kupující:</h2>
        <p class="kupujici"><b>Jméno: </b><ins:value-of select="name/text()"/><ins:text> </ins:text>
            <ins:value-of select="surname/text()"/><br/>
            <b>Adresa: </b><ins:value-of select="/address1/street/text()"/>
            <ins:text> </ins:text>
            <ins:value-of select="address1/number/text()"/>
            <ins:text>, </ins:text>
            <ins:value-of select="address1/postalZone/text()"/>
            <ins:text>, </ins:text>
            <ins:value-of select="address1/city/text()"/> <br/>
            <b>Kontaktní údaje</b><br/>
            <b>telefon: </b> <ins:value-of select="contact/fastContact/telephone/text()"/><br/>
            <b>email: </b> <ins:value-of select="contact/fastContact/email/text()"/>    <br/>    
        </p>        
    </ins:template>

    <ins:template match="sellerParty">
        <h2>Prodávající:</h2>
        <p class="prodavajici"><b>Jméno: </b><ins:value-of select="name/text()"/><br/>
            <b>Adresa: </b><ins:value-of select="address/street/text()"/>
            <ins:text> </ins:text>
            <ins:value-of select="address/number/text()"/>
            <ins:text>, </ins:text>
            <ins:value-of select="address/postalZone/text()"/>
            <ins:text>, </ins:text>
            <ins:value-of select="address/city/text()"/> <br/>
            <b>Kontaktní údaje</b><br/>
            <b>telefon: </b> <ins:value-of select="contact/telephone/text()"/><br/>
            <b>email: </b> <ins:value-of select="contact/email/text()"/>    <br/>    
        </p>        
    </ins:template>

    <ins:template match="invoiceInfo">
        <h2>Obecné údaje:</h2>
        <p class="faktura"><b>Datum vydání: </b><ins:value-of select="issueDate/text()"/><br/>
            <b>Datum splatnosti: </b><ins:value-of select="maturity/text()"/> <br/>
            <b>Identifikační číslo: </b> <ins:value-of select="invoiceNumber/text()"/><br/>
            </p>
    </ins:template>

    <ins:template match="sum">
        <h2>Hodnota:</h2>
        <p class="faktura">
            <b>Celková cena (bez DPH): </b> <ins:value-of select="withoutTax/text()"/><br/>
            <b>Celkové DPH: </b> <ins:value-of select="tax/text()"/><br/>
            <b>Celková cena (s DPH): </b> <ins:value-of select="containingTaxTotal/text()"/><br/>
        </p>
    </ins:template>

    <ins:template match="invoiceLineItems">
        <h3>Zboží:</h3>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Název</td>
                <td>Počet kusů</td>
                <td>Cena (s DPH)</td>
            </tr>
            <ins:for-each select="invoiceItem">
                <ins:sort select="itemName"/>
                <ins:call-template name="akce"/>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{position()}.html"><ins:value-of select="./itemName"/></a></td>
                    <ins:choose>
                        <ins:when test="itemNumber &gt; 1235">
                            <td style="color: red;"><ins:value-of select="./itemNumber"/></td> 
                        </ins:when>
                        <ins:otherwise>
                            <td><ins:value-of select="./itemNumber"/></td>
                        </ins:otherwise>
                    </ins:choose>

                    <td><ins:value-of select="./price/sum/containingTax"/></td>
                </tr>

            </ins:for-each>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>CELKEM</td>
                <td><ins:value-of select="../sum/containingTaxTotal/text()"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ins:template>

    <ins:template name="akce">
        <ins:result-document href="{position()}.html">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Zboží číslo <ins:value-of select="position()"/></title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="invoice.css"/>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="hlavni">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Název</td>
                            <td>Cena (bez DPH)</td>
                            <td>Cena (s DPH)</td>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><ins:value-of select="./itemName"/></td>
                                <td><ins:value-of select="./price/perUnit/withoutTax"/></td>
                                <td><ins:value-of select="./price/perUnit/containingTax"/></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                        <p>
                            <a href="invoice.html"><ins:text>Zpět na hlavní stranu</ins:text></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>           
        </ins:result-document>
    </ins:template>

</ins:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "Must use namespaces" is a ridiculous requirement unless it says why or how you must use namespaces. It's like saying your code must contain comments: anyone can write code that contains comments, but unless the comments say something meaningful, they are useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce a valid output HTML document you just need to add `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xslFormatting"` on the `<ins:stylesheet>` (root) element of your stylesheet.

But indeed in your stylesheet you don't use the *xsi* and *xslFormatting* namespaces anywhere. Thus you could also modify your stylesheet by removing these namespaces declarations, leading you to :

```
<ins:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:ins="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://josefdraslar.cz/">
```

The only namespace that would be required is bound to the "http://josefdraslar.cz/" URI, because it is the default namespace of your input XML, but since you declared `xpath-default-namespace="http://josefdraslar.cz/"`, you properly use this namespace in your XSLT.